# How to save multiple column in database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a text file.I need to get data from this text file and show on grid ,

```
1)After this user can update information  from gridview, 
2)Click on save button save data on database.
```

Before clicking on button data don't save on database.How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"In my text file, I have more than 1000 rows, how to save them in temp database? I want to save them by using stored procedure, how to save multiple bits of data by executing one procedure?"

You can use [`SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy%28VS.80%29.aspx) for this.

The textfile can be the source for the bulk copy:

http://blog.stevienova.com/2008/01/16/net-fastest-way-to-load-text-file-to-sql-sqlbulkcopy/